# How class/object relationships implemented in PHP

Tags: php, class, relationship

```
hypernym-hyponym (supertype-subtype) relations between types (classes) defining a taxonomic hierarchy, where
    for a subsumption relation: a hyponym (subtype, subclass) has a type-of (is-a) relationship with its hypernym (supertype, superclass);
holonym-meronym (whole/entity/container-part/constituent/member) relations between types (classes) defining a possessive hierarchy, where
    for an aggregation (i.e. without ownership) relation:
        a holonym (whole) has a has-a relationship with its meronym (part),
    for a composition (i.e. with ownership) relation:
        a meronym (constituent) has a part-of relationship with its holonym (entity),
    for a containment[1] relation:
        a meronym (member) has a member-of relationship with its holonym (container);
concept-object (type-token) relations between types (classes) and objects (instances), where
    a token (object) has an instance-of relationship with its type (class).
```

Above is quote from Wiki article on [Is-a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) and [has-a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a) relationship between classes in OOP.

I want to see examples of each type of relationship from quoted using PHP syntax. Let me know if i am correct about this.

First **supertype-subtype**

```
abstract class User {...}

class Student extends User {...}
class Employee extends User {...}
```

Second **whole/entity/container-part/constituent/member** is what confuses me.

**aggregation** is done in PHP trough dependency injection?

```
   class Car_Wheel {...} 

   $wheel = new Car_Wheel();

   class Car {

      private $wheel;

      public __construct($wheel) {
         $this->wheel = $wheel;   
      }
   }

   $Car = new Car($wheel);
```

**Composition** achieved in php trough `traits` or `includes`?

```
trait Car_Wheel {...}

class Car {

   use Car_Wheel;

   ...
}
```

or

```
//file `car_wheel.php`

...
private function car_wheel_rotate(...) {};
...

//file `car.php`

class Car {} {

   include_once "car_wheel.php";

   ...
}
```

**Containment** achieved in php trough instantiating object inside object?

```
class Car_Wheel {...} 
class Car_Seat {...}

class Car {
   private $wheel;
   private $seat;

   public __construct() {
      $this->wheel = new Car_Wheel();   
      $this->seat = new Car_Seat();   
   }   
}
```

Third is **type-token** also simple

```
class Database {...}

$DB = new Database();
```

Comment: Given the description, your "containment" example seems backwards. `class Wheel { private $car; ... }` And composition doesn't involve traits; it involves object like all the others.

Comment: Why its backwards? i thought car consists of wheels, seats etc not other way around. so why should wheel contain car? What are traits for then?

Comment: Traits are a way for classes to share implementation code without requiring inappropriate relationships. They impose no relationship of their own (except whatever the code of the trait imposes), and have nothing more to do with inheritance, aggregation, composition, etc than Ctrl+V would. And yes, a car consists of wheels, seats, etc. That would be composition, though, as cars don't create wheels or seats. My gripe is more with the description, as it's rather confusingly (i'd argue _misleadingly_) worded.

Comment: Okay what should go under **Composition** feel free to post a response, because i feel like include is not a relationship either.